# Joomla 3.x Administrator Error : 0 Cannot write to log

Tags: php, joomla

I wrote a joomla 3.x simple web site on my local machine and it worked fine.  I deployed this to 1&1.com and the front end works fine but the control panel throws an error each time I try to log in saying "0: cannot write to log".

I have tried relative and absolute paths to the log folder in the $log_path parameter of the configuration.php and changed the permissions to the folder and files to all sorts of combinations and still I get the same error?  I have created a new log folder and pointed the  to that and still no joy?

has anyone come across this error using 1&1.com?  I see some suggestions that 1&1.com are really bad with joomla support and I may be best trying another host?  I am in 30 day money back guarantee so that is going to be my next move.

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check this link https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4673/error-0-cannot-open-file-for-writing-log-while-updating and if everything is fine and still this doesnt help then proceed to next step

**Step:1** get the base path by writing this code to a file and uploading it through ftp

```
<?php
 $basepath = getcwd();
 echo "Your base Path is: ";
 echo $basepath;
 ?>
```

When you run that file suppose it is named base.php then go to http://yoursite.com/base.php and get your base path.

**Step:2** Create a new log and tmp folder

Now as You have got the base path, create a folder in your main joomla installation and name it newlog with permission 755.

**Step:3** Change path in GLobal Configuration

In your global configuration give the base path appending the new folder path. Suppose you get basepath as `/var/www/joomla` then uou give the log path as
`/var/www/joomla/newlog`

Comment: hi amit, thanks for your reply.  The issue was two fold.  I used that script above yesterday to get my absolute path but that didn't work.  I needed to prefix it with " /kunden/", no idea why???  Once I did that, I got an admininstrator username and password do not match or you do not have an account error when logging in.  I went into my MySQL database and saw that this user was not active.  Once I activated the admiin user it worked just fine.

Comment: Is your joomla site installed inside kunden folder? Seems someone played with your database. How can admin account be inactivated. Sometimes some plugins too create nuisance. Its good that now its working.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you might have asked 1&1 already, it may be something they know very well.

Anyway make sure you have the correct configuration paths (absolute!) in the configuration.php and that the folder and its files are writable by the user who runs the website instance.

Also clear /cache and /administrator/cache for good measure, as they may have cached some non-authenticated results.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, not the answer for me, but good suggestion so +1 :)